# How do I convert ArrayFire Image to Julia Image?

Tags: julia, arrayfire, plots.jl

I want to use the plotting functionality of Plots.jl with an image loaded using the `load_image()` function of ArrayFire.

What I have is :

```
AFArray: 1000×300×3 Array{Float32,3}
```

What I want is :

```
300×1000 Array{RGB{Any},2} with eltype RGB
```

I couldn't be able to find direct conversion in documentations. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know specifically about ArrayFire arrays, but in general you can use `reinterpret` for operations like this. If you want the new array to reside on the cpu, then copy it over.

Then, ideally, you could just do

```
rgb = reinterpret(RGB{Float32}, A)
```

Unfortunately, MxNx3 is not the optimal layout for RGB arrays, since you want the 3-values to be located sequentially. So you should either make sure that the array has 3xMxN-layout, or you can do `permutedims(A, (3, 1, 2))`.

Finally, to get a matrix, you must drop the leading singleton dimension, otherwise you get a 1xMxN array.

So,

```
rgb = dropdims(reinterpret(RGB{Float32}, permutedims(A, (3, 1, 2))); dims=1)
```

I assumed that you actually want `RGB{Float32}` instead of `RGB{Any}`.

BTW, I'm not sure how this will work if you want to keep the final array on the GPU.

**Edit:** You might consider `reshape` instead of `dropdims`, it seems slightly faster on my pc.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir but that takes almost a full minute on my GPU taking 40% of its capacity on a single 100kb jpg, where the crucial part in my program is the speed. Also, the RGB channels are needlessly scaled to 255, and all I see on the screen is white. I want to say that my main reason to use Plots is to make use of its labels and axes, by reading the files directly into GPU my code became 3 times faster, should I keep trying the reinterpret function, or is there any better way to draw axes on an image with ticks and labels?

Comment: On my computer `dropdims(reinterpret(RGB{Float32}, permutedims(A, (3, 1, 2))); dims=1)` takes <700microseconds for a 1000x300x3 array, and just 300 nanoseconds for a 3x1000x300 array. So I assume it must be communication with the GPU that takes the time. What does your code look like? Skipping the GPU would be faster. As for saturation, 0 is black and 1 is white, so everything should be scaled inside that interval.

Comment: that's interesting, I have a function called `createBigFrame` that combines 30 images into a single with `load_image` function inside which gives me `AFArray: 1000×300×3 Array{Float32,3}` in 0.03 seconds, after that I ran your code on a separate block and it took 76 seconds

Comment: Yes, I assume it's the communication between the cpu and the gpu that is taking the time. I'm no expert on Images.jl, but I don't know if you can use `RGB` arrays on the gpu. In that case, if you really want `Array{RGB, 2}`, you may be better off dropping the gpu, since the data ends up back on the cpu anyway. Perhaps there is some way to do this *entirely* on the gpu, but I don't know how.

Comment: BTW, this type of question could be well suited to ask on https://discourse.julialang.org (remember to include a link to this question, in that case.)

Comment: Thanks for determining what the problem is, that helps me a lot.

Comment: You can transfer back to the CPU with `Array(afa)` where `afa` is your `AFArray`. See the README: https://github.com/JuliaGPU/ArrayFire.jl

Comment: Transferring the array to CPU with `Array(afa)` and then doing the conversion eliminated the waiting time.